# Does TeXlive 2012 come with TrueType or OpenType equivalents to common fonts used with latex?

Tags: fonts, texlive, opentype, truetype

I'm using the package `helvet` in a document and would like to use the same font in a figure I'm making. Does TeXlive 2012 come with the TrueType or OpenType fonts that correspond to the helvetica clone used in `helvet`? Also, does it come with the same files for other common fonts that come with the distribution?

Comment: TeX Gyre Heros is a clone of Helvetica and it is available in OpenType format. What's the setting in which you want to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Most LaTeX fonts are composed of 'other kind' of source files that can not easily be used in other programs. Some fonts also include TrueType or OpenType files but that is not guaranteed: you'll have to look it up for the font you use.

In your situation I suggest you switch to TeX Gyre Heros (`tgheros`) as it's an enhanced version of Helvetica. Depending on how you installed TeXlive 2012 they might already have been installed on your system so you can use them right away. If that is not the case: all TeX Gyre fonts can also [be downloaded in OpenType format](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre).